# how to limit the rows of a datagridview with a textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that shows me the data of only one table in Sql server 2014, I need the rows of that datagridview to change according to the number that is entered in a textbox. thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you show your code as a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the value of the textbox to your sql as a **parameter** (let's call it `@Top`) and then add `TOP (@Top)` to the beginning of your `SELECT` statement.

Don't forget to ensure you have an `ORDER BY` as well, to have consistent results each time you run the query (otherwise they could be random).

So, in Pseudo-SQL terms, you end up with a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (@Top) {Columns} ... FROM {Tables with JOINs} ... WHERE ... ORDER BY {Column List};
```

Comment: Really thanks, but I still have a problem, what I need is that the data sorted from the table from highest to lowest is shown to me in the datagridview, and then, when entering a quantity in a textbox, only the number of rows entered in the textbox is shown to me in the datagridview, to later make a report. thanks!!!